# Excel: Want to scan bar code then tab to next column instead of moving down a line in the same column

Tags: microsoft-excel, barcode-scanner, barcode

My question is how can I scan a bar code and tab to the next column in Excel instead of moving down vertically in the same column?

I am using a Powerscan PM9500

Answer (score 1):

You can change the direction of pressing Enter.

See https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/make-enter-key-excel-move-different-direction/ for instructions

Go to File -> Options

[image]

This may or may not work not sure if you’re scanner is pressing enter after a scan. (I’m guessing it does)

Answer (score 1):

Additionally to @PeterH 's answer, you can also modify your barcodes as to replace the EOL character with a form field control `Tab` character instead of a `Line Return`.  Depending on your barcode and scanner system, it's possible you may need to consult the OEM of the scanner units or the barcode encoding software.

EDIT: I just noticed you had included the model number of your barcode scanner!  Please refer to your product's [user manual](https://www.bsr.at/mediafiles/Handbuch/Datalogic/Technische-Dokumentation-Powerscan9500_rev_g.pdf) starting from page 341, which will walk you through how to input form field control characters for each applicable platform.  In case the link ever breaks, I've hosted a copy [here](https://1drv.ms/b/s!Au6FcD8kvdA9gZpVLVLXLrbsNiuGfw?e=vecFY9) as well.